# How to Transpose Column values to new dataframe column headers and add data below that headers in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a table(dataframe) by using some live data fields which will be updating in some fixed time and as soon as data updates I need to add that data into my table
I get data in tabular format like below

```
Time        col1        col2        col3
timestapm1   123        456         789
timestamp2   7584       4547        6545
timestamp3   8974       1241        2140
```

When script run for first time then it create new seprate list of column names for my desired table by using above data which looks like below

```
Timestamp col1_456  col1_4547   col1_1241   col3_456    col3_4547   col3_1241
```

**col1** and **col3** values changes regularly, **col2 is static** . I'm just getting confused at how can I match the column names of new table and add value under that column.

```
Time        col1        col2        col3
timestapm4   17823      456         10789
timestamp5   758404     4547        65045
timestamp6   89744      1241        14140
```

Desired output

```
Timestamp   col1_456    col1_4547   col1_1241   col3_456    col3_4547   col3_1241
timestamp4  17823       758404      89744       10789       65045       14140
```

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this. I used your example data for `df1` and `df2`, pivoted it and concat them together, everytime you get new data, you can run these 3 lines of code ( change timestamp, pivot, concat) where the new data is appended as new rows to the existing dataframe `output`. Changing the column `Time` to a single value is needed to make it one row in your `output`, you can change that name for every data chunk you receive to make the rows distinct.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Time": {0: "timestamp1", 1: "timestamp2", 2: "timestamp3"},
        "col1": {0: 123, 1: 7584, 2: 8974},
        "col2": {0: 456, 1: 4547, 2: 1241},
        "col3": {0: 789, 1: 6545, 2: 2140},
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Time": {0: "timestapm4", 1: "timestamp5", 2: "timestamp6"},
        "col1": {0: 17823, 1: 758404, 2: 89744},
        "col2": {0: 456, 1: 4547, 2: 1241},
        "col3": {0: 10789, 1: 65045, 2: 14140},
    }
)

df1["Time"] = "timestamp_1"
tmp1 = df1.pivot(index="Time", columns="col2", values=["col1", "col3"]).reset_index()
tmp1.columns = tmp1.columns.map(lambda x: f"{x[0]}_{x[1]}")

df2["Time"] = "timestamp_2"
tmp2 = df2.pivot(index="Time", columns="col2", values=["col1", "col3"]).reset_index()
tmp2.columns = tmp2.columns.map(lambda x: f"{x[0]}_{x[1]}")

output = pd.concat([tmp1, tmp2])

print(output)

         Time_  col1_456  col1_1241  col1_4547  col3_456  col3_1241  col3_4547
0  timestamp_1       123       8974       7584       789       2140       6545
0  timestamp_2     17823      89744     758404     10789      14140      65045
```

Comment: Thanks @Rabinzel
yes, but this code will erase previous data, I need to append new data. I want to keep old data as well and want to add new updated below that

Comment: you need to adjust the line of code with `pd.concat`, like: `output = pd.concat([output, current_data])`. Then your `output` always adds the new data to the old data.

Comment: Does it work for you now?

Comment: Sorry @Rabinzel but its not solving my problem. The data I receive is dynamic and col2 values index number gets changed so, I need to match that col2 number of new table with live data field and and add its respective col1 and col3 value into table.